# How to change the size of DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Does anybody know how to change the size of the default DatePicker in SwiftUI? I have been trying to provide a custom frame to resize the DatePicker but I could't see the expected outcome.

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I tried

```
DatePicker("", selection: $currentDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                              .labelsHidden()
                              .frame(width: 150, height: 80, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: i do not think you can do that....like UISwitch they have "fixed sizes" for different environments. You have to write your own custom view if you want this.

Comment: You're basically asking for the Picker that pops up to take up more of the View Controller, right? You could just do a pop up View itself, that might be easier. Let me know if that's what you're trying to do. I have some code for that that I can share :)

Comment: @Kasey I was trying to add date picker in a a custom popup that I built in SwiftUI, but I couldn't customise the size of the date picker. Anyways, someone has answered it, the trick is to just clip the date picker. Thank you for your effort tho, appreciate it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just clip it at the end as below...

```
DatePicker("", selection: $currentDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    .labelsHidden()
    .frame(width: 150, height: 80, alignment: .center)
    .clipped()
```

Comment: this does not work, basically the datepicker still has the same witdth, just the frame from witch you see the picker is smaller but this is not helping because if you put it smaller the content of the picker will be cut

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. I was able to use `clipped()` in `Picker` successfully before the iOS14 update. But now when I use `clipped()`in a `DatePicker` nothing happens to the "scrollable area" of the `DatePicker`.

Comment: Ok. Just figured it out. Add `.compositingGroup()` before the `.clipped()` modifier.

Answer (score 5):

I added .scaleEffect() after the datepicker, and now I can achieve size scaling...

Answer (score 5):

You can change its size using the transform effect , this example will reduce the DatePicker size to be 0.8 of its default size
just add this modifier to the picker

```
DatePicker(......).transformEffect(.init(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8))
```

Answer (score 3):

While changing the size of the native `DatePicker` is still really not possible, it has become easier to build a custom one. In iOS 16.4 Apple introduced `.presentationCompactAdaptation` which makes it possible to pop a date popover like the native `DatePicker`. This way the hacky work around of the original answer is not necessary anymore.

The following code makes the solution as good as possible downwards compatible.

```swift
.popover(isPresented: $showPicker) {
    if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            .frame(width: 320)
            .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
    } else if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            .frame(width: 320)
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
    } else {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            .frame(width: 320)
    }
}
```

### Old answer

While this does not directly tackle the issue of changing the size of the SwiftUI DatePicker, it still might be of interest for people who have to work with a SwiftUI `DatePicker`.

The only way i found to resize a `DatePicker` in SwiftUI was to use the `.scaleEffect()` modifier. So the idea was to create my own UI which passes a tap to the DatePicker it covers, which then shows the popover.

For the view to be fully clickable, the `DatePicker` has to be scaled to cover the whole width. To dynamically calculate this scale factor between the `DatePicker` and the covering UI i used two DatePickers, which i placed behind the covering UI - one two read the native width and one to resize.

The implementation below only scales in the X-Axis since this already achieved what i needed.

```
struct ScalingDatePicker: View {

    @Binding var selection: Date
    @State var datepickerSize: CGSize = .zero
    let displayComponents: DatePicker.Components = [.date]

    static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // Hidden DatePicker to grab the Size for calculations
            DatePicker("", selection: $selection, displayedComponents: displayComponents)
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        Color.clear.onAppear {
                            datepickerSize = geo.size
                        }
                    }
                )
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                .fixedSize()
                .opacity(0)

            GeometryReader { geo in
                DatePicker("", selection: $selection, displayedComponents: displayComponents)
                    .scaleEffect(
                        x: geo.size.width/datepickerSize.width,
                        anchor: .topLeading
                    )
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(6)
                }

                Text(Self.formatter.string(from: selection))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(12)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
//                    .opacity(0.5) // -> use this to see the scaling effect in action
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .strokeBorder(.black)
                    )
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

The size of the date picker can easily be changed manually. If you go over to Main.storyboard and simply click on the Date Picker, its size can easily be adjusted. However, I am not sure if this is possible with code.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Yeah it can be easily changed if you're using UIKit, but Im using SwiftUI. Thanks for your effort tho, appreciate it!